# Raspberry Pi 3 Model B setup startx or sudo startx gives: command not found

Tags: user-interface, raspberry-pi, raspbian

How can I get startx to work?

I have my SD set -used pi filler and image raspbian jessie.

However, I did download the zip Raspbian Jessie Lite (usually I have done the full desktop image, not lite)

After I log in as pi I want to get to my GUI. I type:

```
$startx
-bash: startx: command not found
```

So then I try with sudo, still: command not found.

I have done my steps in the sudo raspi-config to extend file system, set correct time and keyboard.

When I try to install some python packages

I want to configure my wi-fi by running the GUI. But, I cannot get to my gui with startx.

I know a few things (I've had startx work before on other pi 3s, but I'm a big noob, so please be detailed if you can help me out.

Thank you, in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is completely configuration-related and belongs to unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Try `which startx` so you get the full path, then use that with `sudo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lite version of Raspian Jessie doesn't come with X installed. That's why you cannot start it.

Raspbian lite is intended for a headless system usage, however you can still install X (don't ask me how, the web is plenty of tutorials)

Comment: to install X: `sudo apt-get install X` but, I get E: Unable to locate package X. When I try to look around in what I have in my directories, I really don't have much there at all. Can anyone tell me where to go from here to find it? I'll try expanding again, but I have 4GB SD. Usually I have had a 8GB and just download the full Raspbian Jessie, smooth sailing after that. I may just start over and do that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: try with a `sudo apt-get update`. Maybe X is not present in the lite distro repositories, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install lxde
```

after this one gets installed, used the command
`startlxde`

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to install these packages

```
sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-video-fbdev xinit pciutils xinput xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-scalable
```

Answer (score 0):

use `sudo apt-get install xinit` instead.

Don't forget to expand your File System and reboot: `sudo raspi-config`